# Turn the body of an individual message into a string

Tags: gmail-api

I am using users.messages.get() to lookup data on an individual message.  I would like to parse through the body of the message and would like to know 1) what field will return the body of an individual message into a readable string format, or 2) how to turn the body into readable format string.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to retrieve the message, as you mentioned. I will only ask for the part that contains the message, called the payload. More specifically, the parts of the payload:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/{YOUR_MAIL_ID}?fields=payload%2Fparts&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

This will give you the following object:

```
{
 "payload": {
  "parts": [
   {
    "partId": "0",
    "mimeType": "text/plain",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "size": 56,
     "data": "PGI-IFRoaXMgaXMgYSBib2xkIGV4YW1wbGUgbWFpbCwgZG9uJ3QgeW91IHRoaW5rPyA8L2I-DQo="
    }
   },
   {
    "partId": "1",
    "mimeType": "text/html",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "size": 93,
     "data": "PGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-Jmx0O2ImZ3Q7IFRoaXMgaXMgYSBib2xkIGV4YW1wbGUgbWFpbCwgZG9uJiMzOTt0IHlvdSB0aGluaz8gJmx0Oy9iJmd0OzwvZGl2Pg0K"
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Here you can see the mail in both plain text and html!

One last detail remains. The mail contents are not readable as you can see, since they are still base64-encoded. Press F12 to open up your Developer Tools, and input the contents to the atob()-function to decode them. Since the base64 encoded data also has been made URL-safe, we have to replace all the "-" with "+" and "_" with "/" to make it proper base64.

```
// Plain text version
atob("PGI-IFRoaXMgaXMgYSBib2xkIGV4YW1wbGUgbWFpbCwgZG9uJ3QgeW91IHRoaW5rPyA8L2I-DQo=".replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/\_/g, '/')) 
// => "<b> This is a bold example mail, don't you think? </b>"

// HTML version
atob("PGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-Jmx0O2ImZ3Q7IFRoaXMgaXMgYSBib2xkIGV4YW1wbGUgbWFpbCwgZG9uJiMzOTt0IHlvdSB0aGluaz8gJmx0Oy9iJmd0OzwvZGl2Pg0K".replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/\_/g, '/'))

// => "<div dir="ltr">&lt;b&gt; This is a bold example mail, don&#39;t you think? &lt;/b&gt;</div>"
```

Depending on what language you are using, there are great libraries that can help you with this, but this is the nooks and crannies of it!